# How to get rid of one placeholder at a time when the user types on that line? (swiftUI)

Tags: swiftui, placeholder

I put "placeholders" in my TextEditor. I used .isEmpty but I soon learned that by typing in the TextEditor it gets rid of all placeholders. I only want it to get rid of the appropriate "placeholder" when the user types on that line but not get rid of them all at once. How might I achieve this? [image]

I am starting to think .isEmpty is not the solution for this, but I'm not sure. Ideally I'd like to add a TextField INTO the TextEditor but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is my .isEmpty code which gets rid of both "placeholders" when you type (or even press the space button):

```
ZStack (alignment: .leading){
            
            if test.isEmpty{
                VStack{
                   
                    Text("Recipe Name")
                        .padding(.top,10)
                        .opacity(1)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
            }
            
            if test2.isEmpty{
                VStack{
                   
                    Text("Recipe made by (link if applicable)")
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                        .opacity(1)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                }
            }
            
            VStack{
                TextEditor(text: $note.text)
                    .opacity(note.text.isEmpty ? 0.85 : 1)
                    .font(.custom("SanFrancisco", fixedSize: 20))
                    .onReceive(note.publisher(for: \.text), perform: setName)
                    .onReceive(
                        note.publisher(for: \.text)
                            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                            .removeDuplicates()
                    ){ _ in
                        try? PersistenceController.shared.saveContext()
                    }
                    .navigationTitle(note.name)
            }
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: you could put the recipe name in a `TextField` and underneath have a `TextEditor` for the recipe.

Comment: Well ideally I would like multiple "placeholders" WITHIN the TextEditor so I don't think that would work. It is absolutely not possible to put a TextField within a TextEditor?